# появление echo ' ' php без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, php

подскажите пожалуйста, есть условие в php и после перезагрузки страницы оно работает.
Пример:

```
<? if ($cart_prod['id'] == 1) { echo '<div>'.$cart_prod['qty'].'</div>';} ?>
```

А возможно ли как-нибудь появление "echo" при помощи js без перезагрузки страницы?
Мб запихнуть это условия в функцию и потом по клику :

```
$('div').load("<?php echo base_url(); ?>card_prod/function");
```

Comment: PHP скрипты виполняются на стороне сервера. Тоесть браузер посылает запрос серверу сервер его обрабатывает и отдает результат обработки. Выполнить код PHP можно только на сервере. Для того чтобы добавить сайту динамичности используют аякс (ajax) запросы к серверу, они позволяют отправить на сервер запрос без перезагрузки страницы. В вашем случае можно создать обработчик который будет формировать список товаров и через аякс запрос отправлять например айди карточки и получать список товаров даной карточки.

Comment: http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke#js

Comment: Спасибо большое за обратную связь!